# Insert data in datagridview gives exception

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to use datagridview for show some data(information) to user. My datagridview has 4 column. When I use this code

```
private void sfactor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "book";
        dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "pen";
        dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = "x";
        dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value = "y";
        dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[0].Value = "z";
}
```

I want to show this info just in `column[0]`. When program run, it has exception:

```
Index was out of range.
Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

I know why but I don't know how I can solve it. Now I need your help and your experience. I wait for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the rows before assigning values. There's an overload which lets you create and set values at the same time:

```
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("book");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("pen");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("x");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("y");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("z");
```

Comment: If I want to add "x" in row[3] and column[4],where I can isert number of row and column?

Comment: @mahnaz Once you've added the rows you can address them by index.

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a datatable and fill that up.

Then you can use the datasource property of your datagridview to bind your datatable to the datagridview.